# Timer в android (ошибка)

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Пытаюсь сделать таймер, но безуспешно. Выдает:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста:

```
public class MainActivityCW extends Activity {

    TextView currentCoordinates;

    GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(this);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask updCurrentCoordinates = new UpdateCoordinates();
    private final long UPD_START_DELAY = 1000; // 1 сек = 1000 мс
    private final long UPD_PERIOD = 1000; // 1 сек = 1000 мс

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        currentCoordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentCoordinates);

        timer.schedule(updCurrentCoordinates, 1000, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    public static double c = 0;

    class UpdateCoordinates extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            currentCoordinates.setText(Double.toString(0 + c));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: стек трейс покажите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если мне память не изменяет, то нельзя из таймера к гуятине обращаться.

Используйте [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
class UpdateCoordinates extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivityCW .this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 currentCoordinates.setText(Double.toString(0 + c));
              }
        });          
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает! Пол дня мучался, помогло!

Comment: @СергійРепік тогда отметьте ответ как принятый. Рад, что помогло )

Comment: @SerjR чтобы пол дня не мучаться надо заглядывать в стектрейс ошибки, там четко написано по какой причине появляется ошибка и в какой строке.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую `CountDownTimer`

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```